# JIRA REST API calls fail when using JSESSIONID cookie authentication using urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, jira-rest-api, urlfetch

I have a Google App Engine Python application that interacts with a JIRA Cloud instance.

To date the application makes `urlfetch` calls to JIRA using Basic Authentication but as it is now making dozens of separate REST calls both POST and GET I was hoping that using cookie authentication would reduce the latency somewhat.

example Basic-Authentication code that works:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(jira_url,
                        deadline=60,
                        headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" %
                        base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))
                        })
```

and cookie alternative:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(jira_url,
                        deadline=60,
                        headers={"X-Atlassian-Token": "no-check", 
                        "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=529…snip…C4C"
                        })
```

I retrieved the JSESSIONID successfully using the instructions but the cookie query will only return `"401 - Unauthorized" error while loading this page.` errors as if the cookie has expired.

```
{
  "errorMessages" : [
    "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.",
    "Login Required"
  ],
  "errors" : {}
}
```

I am recalling the cookie from Memcache as most of the interactions are made from a Task Queue and necessarily a separate thread, but the cookie is generated immediately before the recall.

Comment: As a follow-up to this correct and accepted answer, Atlassian has now deprecated cookie-based authentication. There is now only, Basic with dev token or OAuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookie is not expired. The cause of the issue is that JSESSIONID is not the only cookie which is required for the successful authentication of subsequent requests.

I encountered the same issue and solved it by re-sending all cookies I got from the server when creating the session. In my case (the JIRA server is hosted at Atlassian Cloud) these required cookies are: atlassian.xsrf.token and studio.crowd.tokenkey.

I posted a detailed article on this here: [JIRA REST API: Cookie-based Authentication](http://www.marss.co.ua/2016/04/jira-rest-api-cookie-based.html). The example of the code is in C# but the general idea should be clear.

Comment: As a follow-up to this correct and accepted answer, Atlassian has now deprecated cookie-based authentication. There is now only, Basic with dev token or OAuth.